# Quartz Scheduler - Check for running job

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler

I used the below code to check for running jobs. I added this method after the scheduler start. But everytime the running job count is 0. How to check for running job properly?

```
List<JobExecutionContext> currentJobs = scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
for (JobExecutionContext jobCtx: currentJobs){
jobName = jobCtx.getJobDetail().getName();
groupName = jobCtx.getJobDetail().getGroup();
if (jobName.equalsIgnoreCase("job_I_am_looking_for_name") && groupName.equalsIgnoreCase("job_group_I_am_looking_for_name")) {
    //found it!
    logger.warn("the job is already running - do nothing");
             return;
}               
}
```

Source: [find if a job is running in Quartz1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155077/find-if-a-job-is-running-in-quartz1-6)

Comment: Have you checked you have currently running jobs while calling this method? 
Like create a unit tests that schedules a job immediate, 
launches the scheduler,
have the job trigger wait for the test to be ready,
the test checks the getCurrentlyExecutingJobs
then signal the job it can end, 
then leave?

Comment: Thanks, How to easy start with unit test? I dint used that before.

Comment: start with cloning https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet.git, then add a unit test to the ones already present.

Comment: @Hylaean ok let me try thanks...